# How to check if mouse position is inside a circleCollider2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to check if the mouse position is inside a circleCollider2D.

I am checking the collider bounds in Update but that only returns a box not a circle

```
void Update() {
    CircleCollider2D collider2D = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
    Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    Debug.Log(collider2D.bounds.Contains(new Vector2(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y)));
    Debug.DrawLine(collider2D.bounds.ClosestPoint(mousePosition), mousePosition);
}
```

[image: Demo of the problem]

How do I check if the mouse is inside the circle collider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't using the `OnMouseEnter()` Unity Builtin?

Create a script and attach it to the `GameObject` that has the `CircleCollider2D` and add the `OnMouseEnter()` event. Optionally you can also use the `OnMouseExit()` event. `OnMouseEnter()` and `OnMouseExit()` are events that are triggered automatically by `Unity` similar to `OnCollisionEnter(), OnCollisionExit(), OnGuiEnter()` etc...

Comment: Didn't know they existed. Tried it out, works like a charm